# How is my express server reading a req.cookies set as 'httpOnly' ? How would I read it in my front end?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have some troubles understanding this code.

I have the following express login route , it sends an accesstoken as a a response, and then in my frontend i save it in a cookie, and sends a refresh token as... (?) <- i dont understand this phase

```
    app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password} = req.body;

    try{
        //find user in database if not then error
        const user = fakeDB.find(user => user.email === email);
        if(!user) throw new Error("User doesnt exist");
        //compare the passwords and see if they match send error if not
        const valid = await compare(password, user.password);
        if(!valid) throw new Error("Password not corect");
        //create refresh and access token if its correct
        const accesstoken =  createAccessToken(user.id);
        const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken(user.id);
        //put the refreshtoken in the "database"
        user.refreshtoken = refreshtoken;
        console.log(fakeDB);
        //send token refreshtoken as a cookie, and accesstoken as a regular response
        sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken);
        sendAccessToken(res, req, accesstoken);

    }catch (err){
        res.send({
            error: `${err.message}`
        })
    }
})
```

The functions to send the refreshtoken and the accesstoken are the following

```
    const sendAccessToken = (res , req, accesstoken) => {
    res.send({
        accesstoken,
        email: req.body.email

    })
}

const sendRefreshToken = (res, refreshtoken) => {
     res.cookie("refreshtoken", refreshtoken, {
        httpOnly: true,
         path: '/refresh_token'
     })

}
```

And then I have a /refresh_token route to refresh my token , adn this is where im lost, I see that `` `const token = req.cookies.refreshtoken` is being extracted from a cookie, but... how is that happening if the cookie is httponly , isnt it supposed to be non readable? The issue there is that I dont understand how to get that refreshtoken value if im calling that route from the frontend. It somehow gets it in the backend if I use postman, but in my frontend I have no idea how to get it.

```
    app.post('/refresh_token', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.refreshtoken
    //if no token in request
    if(!token) return res.send({accesstoken : ''});
    //if we have a token we verify it
    let payload = null;
    try{
        payload = verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    }catch(err){
        return res.send({accesstoken: ''});
    }
    //if token is valid check if user exist
    const user = fakeDB.find(user => user.id === payload.userId)
    if(!user) return res.send({ accesstoken: ''});
    //if user exists check if refreshtoken exist on user

     if(user.refreshtoken !== token){
         return res.send({accesstoken: ''}) 
     }


    //if token exist create a new Refresh and Accestoken
    const accesstoken = createAccessToken(user.id);
    const refreshtoken =  createRefreshToken(user.id);
    user.refreshtoken = refreshtoken;
    //send new refreshtoken and accesstoken
    sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken);
    return res.send({accesstoken});
})
```

Comment: `http_only` is non readable at the client. The code that reads the cookie in your snippet in run at the server. Obviously, the server **should** be able to read the cookie it issues in the first place.

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks that makes sense then